# perf_event_open in github actions

Tags: linux, github-actions

perf_event_open always returns -1 ("file not found" error) in GitHub Actions (both Ubuntu and CentOS), despite having set /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid to 1.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You should set to `-1` not `1`, no?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911368/what-restriction-is-perf-event-paranoid-1-actually-putting-on-x86-perf

Comment: I think you are referring to the "pid" argument to perf_event_open (which I indeed set to -1).  I am talking about the paranoid file.

Comment: I mean that setting. Do you want to set to 1? It's more restrictive.