# How to benchmark a C program

Tags: linux-kernel, valgrind, perf, strace, ftrace

I wrote server and client programs in C and ran them on my Beaglebone platform with different Linux versions (I compiled it). However, the performance of the old Linux version(2.6) is better than the new Linux version(4.9).

So I need to do some profiling to find the time cost of functions, etc.

```
//server snippet
while(1){
    if(read(new_socket, buf, sizeof(int)) <= 0)
        break;

    // timecost start
    if(!init){
        gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        init = 1;
    }

    c++;
    if (c / 1000000 != print){
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        printf("%d (%d) tot: %ld, last: %ld\n", print, count,
            get_usec(begin, end), get_usec(start, end));
        print = c / 1000000;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    }
    // timecost end

    count++;
    send(new_socket, buf, sizeof(int), 0);
}
```

```
//client snippet
while (1)
{
    send(client_fd, buf, sizeof(int), 0);
    if (read(client_fd, buf, sizeof(int)) <= 0)
        break;

    // timecost start
    if(!init){
        gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        init = 1;
    }

    c++;
    if (c / 1000000 != print){
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        printf("%d (%d) tot: %ld, last: %ld\n", print, count,
                get_usec(begin, end), get_usec(start, end));
        print = c / 1000000;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    }
    // timecost end

    count++;
}
```

**the result I got on old/new linux kernels,**

```
2.x kernel:
0 (1999999) tot: 4609998, last: 4609984
1 (3999999) tot: 9150170, last: 4540120

4.x kernel:
0 (1999999) tot: 9451743, last: 9451729
1 (3999999) tot: 18892372, last: 9440623
```

Are there any tools that can be used to debug/profile to find the system call usage/ kernel time cost?

I did a perf record/report on the server process, every function costs more CPU on old kernel.

```
old:
    39.54%   server  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch
     5.02%   server  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
     2.59%   server  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] nf_hook_slow
new: 
    24.74%  server   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] finish_task_switch
     2.67%  server   [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] nf_hook_slow
```

Comment: Does `perf record` / `perf report` work to show you where CPU time is being spent (including in the kernel)?  I guess it won't on Linux 2.x so you might need older tools.  What compiler version / options did you use?  Hopefully `gcc -O3 -march=native` or something like that, or `-O3 -mcpu=something`.

Comment: @PeterCordes From the perf report, every function in 2.x  uses more CPU than the 4.x kernel.

Comment: Are you only profiling user-space, or only looking at percentages rather than absolute times?  Because your measurements show the total time is slower under a 4.x kernel, so obviously *something* is using more time.  Use `perf_event_paranoid = 0` (or perhaps `sudo`) to profile kernel code as well.  ([What restriction is perf\_event\_paranoid == 1 actually putting on x86 perf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51911368)).

Comment: Of course this assumes `perf record` fully works under a 2.x kernel which might not be the case; it might only be using an event like `task-clock` (a software timer), not hardware performance counters for a `cycles` event, if PAPI (the Perf API) isn't supported under your ancient 2.x kernel.

Comment: from your edit: you're looking at percentages of a larger total time.  If those functions take the same absolute time but something else is slower, they'll have a lower percentage.  Look for the thing that's taking more time and compare its details between versions.

Comment: One random thing that I'd like to mention is `spectre` (& co.) that wasn't a known thing in the era of Linux 2.x, but started to show up around Linux 4.15-ish - mitigations are usually enabled by default, and they come with a performance hit.

Comment: @skandigraun Thanks,  performance significantly improved :).